# how to change font in other class textview

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I am using UIFont in textview but not working UIFont because of I am using masterViewClass in that passing array and that array of object passing to detailViewController class and detailViewController class I have passing textview. In that array of object passing to textview but in that use

```
msgtxtView.text=selectedmsg;

[msgtxtView setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana-Italic" size:0]];
```

so, selectedmsg is my array in that passing list of message but that message text in not pass the font and size so, other class means detailViewController class in that how chang font and size give any suggestion and source code which is apply in my code

Comment: asked sane question twice but twisting the scenario don't do this

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're selectedmsg is not showing up in the msgtxtView?

In this case you have to address the string you want to display, not the whole array, like this:

```
msgtxtView.text = [selectedmsg objectAtIndex:0];
```